# Can't find nginx error logs

Tags: nginx

I'm getting a `500 Internal Server Error` in my browser, but I can't find the nginx logs to debug them. Here is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
worker_processes 1;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections  3000;
}

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

You would think that they are in `/var/log/nginx.error.log`, but nope, that file is completely empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Does nginx have permission to write to  /var/log/nginx/access.log ?

Comment: if the server you are requesting has a different error log it would overwrite the default, check the config of the website in the `sites-enabled` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think they would be in /var/log/nginx/error.log

Also take a look in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/debug` the logging paths can be overridden in them.

Comment: This line appears `error_log /srv/webapps/snb/log/nginx-error.log;`, so I looked there and the only errors I see are "File does not exist" errors, nothing that would point to a 500 error